# Exception handling doesnt save variable as correct value

Tags: c#

I am making a bus simulator for school, I am trying to make it as foolproof as possible, there is supposed to be different methods, and the first method is messing up for me. I added a try catch exception handling so that the program doesnt crash. The first method is adding passanger, first gender, then age and then destination. So I let 1 and 2 represent gender, 1 man, 2 woman. The exception handling works except for the most important thing, if it gets invoked the gender doesnt get saved. So when I use the 2nd method which is "show passengers" this happens. Lets say I accidently pressed enter at "enter gender", and then I press 1 to represant man and then 23 years of age and then destination 5 this happens when I invoke method 2 to see passengers.

0, 23, 5

But it's supposed to be

1, 23 ,5

For clarification, at the exception handling there is a method for letting the user try to type the age again instead of it jumping to the next line of code. If someone knows a better way for that too feel free to tell me :)

```
public void add_Passenger()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("You've chosen to add passenger.Start with gender, type 1 for male and 2 for female.");
        var passenger = new Passenger();
       
        try 
        {
            int gender = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            do
            {
                if (gender == 1 | gender == 2)
                {
                    passenger.Gender = gender;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect choice, try again!.");
                    gender = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            } while (gender >= 3);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
              Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input, try again!");
              ChooseTheGender();
        }

        
        Console.WriteLine("Now enter the passengers age.");
        passenger.Age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Now enter the passengers destination in numbers.");
        passenger.Destination = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        passengers_list.Add(passenger);
    }
```

method for choosing gender

```
public static void ChooseTheGender()
    {
        var Passenger = new Passenger();
        int gender = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        try
        {
            
            do
            {
                if (gender == 1 | gender == 2)
                {
                    Passenger.Gender = gender;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ogiltlig val! Försök igen.");
                    gender = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            } while (gender != 1 && gender != 2);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ogiltlig input, försök igen!");
            ChooseTheGender();
        }
    }
```

Comment: We're missing the code for `ChooseTheGender`, but offhand it looks like `gender` is a local variable in the `add_Passanger` method

Comment: First, Instead of wrapping `int.Parse` in a `try...catch` block, use `int.TryParse`. Second, your loop condition doesn't take into consideration the fact that an int can also be 0 or -324. Third, You're not validating the age at all. What's stopping the user from entering 563 or -6 as age?

Comment: Sorry mureinik i added it now, i thought it wasnt important for this.

Zohar yes I know but I am currently working on the gender, I am going through each thing and trying to "foolproof" it one code at a time

Comment: It works here by chance, but you probably want to use `||` instead of `|` for 'or'.

Comment: Should I just paste in the whole program instead? I thought it would be too long confusing to read. Now after I changed the code a bit the exception handling just works 1 time and lets the user retry, after pressing enter again after first time it takes me back to the main menu

Comment: No. That's enough to address the specific problem. You are using local variables. Their value is lost as soon as they go out of scope. You need to return them (i e. their value in case of int) or set a shared state object with their value.

Comment: If it's not for learning purposes, you might find [ExtendedConsole](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedConsole) useful. It has methods such as `ReadInt` that can help you reduce a lot of code. Full disclosure: Written and maintained by me.

Comment: Hmm, sorry guys but I don't really understand. This is my first programming course and I think that try.intparse is too complicated for me rn and for this course.

Fildor how do I do that, return them? I tried to add return; but it just brought me back to the main ,menu

Comment: int.TryParse() is actually simpler to understand than catching exceptions. Although it seems the reverse. TryParse is more 'honest' about its complexity. Exceptions lure you in and bite you from behind with all kinds of complexity. That said, wish you all the best in learning about programming!

Comment: The actual problem you are facing is this: if the very first try is "correct", everything works. If the first input is wrong, you no longer assign the value you receive to `Passenger.Gender`. Instead you assign it to a variable `gender` which gets lost to the ether. In your `ChooseTheGender` method it is even worse, as you create a new Passenger, which then gets lost. You would need to `return` it.

Answer (score 2):

You should most likely use [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0) instead of exceptions. A good way to make code like this simpler is to put it into a separate method

```
public int GetValidNumber(params int[] validValues) => GetValidNumber(validValues.ToHashSet());
public int GetValidNumber(HashSet<int> validValues){
   while(true){
      if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var num) && 
            validValues.Contains(num)){
        return num;
      }
      else{
          Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input, try again!");
      }
   }
}
```

This should help avoid issues like repeated checks etc.

You should then be able to replace most of your code with

```
var gender = GetValidNumber(1, 2);
```

But you might want to consider using an enum and [Enum.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?source=recommendations&view=net-7.0) instead. It makes the parsing code a little bit more complex, but should make the code easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time with this but I think this is too complicated for the current course im doing, It's first grade in HS level. But I appreaciate you taking your time

Comment: @babula40 While enums might be overkill, I would argue that using TryParse, as in my example, makes the code much *less* complicated. There is no longer any recursion, exception handling etc. Your posted example will fail if you input a `3` or any negative number twice, and problems like this happen because you have inputs and checks all over the place. If you think HashSet is to complicated you could replace that with a simple `gender == 1 | gender == 2` check.

Comment: Thanks alot Jonas, I am gonna try to finish the whole assignment firsta and then try to implement this. If I understand correctly do I make one of those codes you typed above for each input and into seperate methods? One for gender, age and destination?

Comment: @babula40 No, use the same method if possible, but if you want to accept a range of numbers you could consider using a [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) instead of a hashSet

Answer (score 1):

Let's *extract method* (we don't want to repeat ourselves three times for `Gender`, `Age` and `Destination`) for the input: we want obtain a `int` value which fits some *extra validation*:

```
private static int ReadInteger(string title, 
                               Func<int, bool> validation = default) {
  // In case of no validation we assume that any integer value is valid
  validation ??= (int x) => true;

  // keep asking user
  while (true) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title)) 
      Console.WriteLine(title);  

    // until valid value is provided 
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result) && validation(result))  
      return result;

    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect choice, try again!.");
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as follow:

```
HashSet<int> knownDestinations = new HashSet<int>() {
  1, 2, 5, 123
};

...

Console.WriteLine("You've chosen to add passenger.");

var passenger = new Passenger() {
  Gender      = ReadInteger("Start with gender, type 1 for male and 2 for female.", 
                             x => x == 1 || x == 2),
  Age         = ReadInteger("Now enter the passengers age.", 
                             x => x >= 0 || x <= 122),
  Destination = ReadInteger("Now enter the passengers destination in numbers.", 
                             x => knownDestinations.Contains(x))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with the other answers and I think you can learn a lot from them. But if you are only starting to learn programming, I suggest to keep it simple. I would implement three methods for the three parameters. I included the method for getting the gender.

```cs
public void add_Passenger()
{
    var passenger = new Passenger();
    passenger.Gender = ChooseTheGender();

    passenger.Age = ChooseTheAge();
    passenger.Destination = ChooseTheDestination()
}

public static int ChooseTheGender()
{
    Console.WriteLine("You've chosen to add passenger.Start with gender, type 1 for male and 2 for female.");
    while (true)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int gender))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid integer");
        }
        else if (gender != 1 && gender != 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect choice, try again!");
        }
        else
        {
            return gender;
        }
    }
}
```

This method tries to parse the user input in an endless loop, so if it fails it tries again. If it can parse it, but it doesn't match the requirements, it tries again. If it succeeds and matches the requirements, it returns the parsed value, which **gets assigned to `passenger.Gender`**!

If you do not like `TryParse` you can try the following version. It is functionally equivalent, but I would use `TryParse` because it is more clear what you are trying to do:

```cs
public static int ChooseTheGender()
{
    Console.WriteLine("You've chosen to add passenger.Start with gender, type 1 for male and 2 for female.");
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            int gender = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
            if (gender != 1 && gender != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect choice, try again!");
            }
            else
            {
                return gender;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid integer");
        }
    }
}
```